# HMMlearn Gaussian Mixture: set mean, weight and variance of each mixture component

Tags: python, hmmlearn

I am using the HMMlearn module to generate a HMM with a Gaussian Mixture Model.

The problem is I want to initialize the mean, variance and weight of each mixture component before I fit the model to any data.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [HHMlean documentation](http://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#building-hmm-and-generating-samples)

> Each HMM parameter has a character code which can be used to customize
>   its initialization and estimation. EM algorithm needs a starting point
>   to proceed, thus prior to training each parameter is assigned a value
>   either random or computed from the data. It is possible to hook into
>   this process and provide a starting point explicitly. To do so
>
> 1. ensure that the character code for the parameter is missing from
>      init_params and then
> 2. set the parameter to the desired value.

Here is an example:

```
model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3, n_iter=100, init_params="t")
model.startprob_ = np.array([0.6, 0.3, 0.1])
model.means_ = np.array([[0.0, 0.0], [3.0, -3.0], [5.0, 10.0]])
model.covars_ = np.tile(np.identity(2), (3, 1, 1))
```

Another example for initializing a `GMMHMM`

```
model = hmm.GMMHMM(n_components=3, n_iter=100, init_params="smt")
model.gmms_ = [sklearn.mixture.GMM(),sklearn.mixture.GMM(),sklearn.mixture.GMM()]
```

The GMMs themselves can be initialised in a very similar way using its attributes and by providing in the `init_params` string, which attributes should be initialize by the constructor.

Comment: Wait, this is for a standard Gaussian HMM not a mixture (which is GMMHMM). What are the attribute names for the mixture? Particularly weight and variance?

Comment: you mean the [`gmms_` attribute](http://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hmmlearn.hmm.GMMHMM)? You can initialise it using a list of `sklearn.mixture.GMM` objects.