# Params argument in hmmlearn GMMHMM not working as intended

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

I have one-dimensional (single feature) data that I want to fit a GMMHMM to. There are two hidden states and I know the probability distribution of the output from each of the states. That is, I know the prior distribution and hence the GMM parameters. So I don't want the hmmlearn object to update the *means*, *covars*, *weights* of the GMMs.

I want to accomplish this using the *params* and *init_params* arguments by setting them to update only *startprob* and *transmat*.

But hmmlearn ends up updating the *means*, *covars*, *weights* as well. How do I stop it from updating these and get it to update only *startprob* and *transmat*?

Here's my code

```
# Initialize the GMMHMM

means_prior = known_means
covars_prior = known_covars
weights_prior = known_weights

gmm_hmm = hmm.GMMHMM(n_components=n_comps, n_mix=n_mix, weights_prior=weights_prior,
                    means_prior=means_prior, covars_prior=covars_prior,
                     covariance_type='spherical', params='st', init_params='st')
gmm_hmm.means_ = means_prior
gmm_hmm.weights_ = weights_prior
gmm_hmm.covars_ = covars_prior

print('Before fitting...')
print('means')
print(gmm_hmm.means_)
print('weights')
print(gmm_hmm.weights_)
print('covars')
print(gmm_hmm.covars_)

# Fit the GMMHMM to the input sequence
gmm_hmm.fit(input_sequence)

print('After fitting...')
print('means')
print(gmm_hmm.means_)
print('weights')
print(gmm_hmm.weights_)
print('covars')
print(gmm_hmm.covars_)
```

You can see that the *weights* and *covars* have changed even though *means* has remained the same.

```
Before fitting...
means
[[[51.30211436]
  [53.32515359]]

 [[63.47895865]
  [57.19121711]]]
weights
[[0.58624271 0.41375729]
 [0.48605807 0.51394193]]
covars
[[ 0.6483754   1.2042972 ]
 [13.85258908  1.04639497]]

After fitting...
means
[[[51.16975532]
  [54.19504787]]

 [[65.82853658]
  [54.25868767]]]
weights
[[0.88971249 0.11028751]
 [0.30707459 0.69292541]]
covars
[[ 0.56903044  0.70862057]
 [14.77828965  0.56072741]]
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

**GMMHMM Documentation**

*init_params : Controls which parameters are initialized prior to training. Can contain any combination of 's' for startprob, 't' for transmat, 'm' for means, 'c' for covars, and 'w' for GMM mixing weights. Defaults to all parameters.*

*params : Controls which parameters are updated in the training process. Can contain any combination of 's' for startprob, 't' for transmat, 'm' for means, and 'c' for covars, and 'w' for GMM mixing weights.Defaults to all parameters.*

Comment: Similar question below. But it is outdated since hmmlearn GMMHMM no longer has the *gmms_* attribute. Also I am doing more or less what is suggested here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970387/hmmlearn-gaussian-mixture-set-mean-weight-and-variance-of-each-mixture-compone?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hmmlearn.hmm.GaussianHMM
Try using the `startprob_prior` and `transmat_prior` parameters when initializing the model.

```
model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=n_components, startprob_prior=pi_mat, transmat_prior=a_mat)
```